# How do I successfully install mysql and mysql-python connector?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need to install Django, Mysql and Mysql python connector Mac os x Yosemite.
I successfully installed Django.
And I think I installed mysql too from seeing the mysql icon in system preference.
And this Mysql-python connector............I did every possible way and could not get it working.

How do I install it? I downloaded the dmg file from the website and installed it. and I typed "mysqld" in the prompt..
it produces a lot of lines with some error message saying its aborting.
And I have python 2.7 and 3.4 in my system. How do I go about this as well?

mysqld doens't work , does that mean mysql did not install correctly? or 
does it have something to do with mysql-python connector??

Comment: [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-06-10 01:50:35 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.24) starting as process 5540 ...
2015-06-10 01:50:35 5540 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.24-osx10.8-x86_64/2015-06-10 01:50:35 5540 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-06-10 01:50:35 5540 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you have the following **installed in your virtual-environment**:

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
PyMySQL==0.6.6
```

Once the above is confirmed, you need to make the following changes to your **settings.py** file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '', 
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '', 
    },
}
```

Install mysql by typing `brew install mysql`

In your bash_profile file, add the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

Once the installation for mysql is complete, in the terminal type:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

mysql service will start running. In another terminal, type mysql. You will mysql console. Create database "db_name" by typing `CREATE database db_name`

Once the database is created, inside your django project directory type `python manage.py syncdb`. And you are done.

Comment: Now I just confimed that I have mysql installed on my mac osx. Because I typed mysql and it got into the mysql prompt. But the rest of the process is still there.  I need to install python-mysql connector lib for my python3.